# Converter String em INT

Tags: java, sql, string

Como converter a string da variável `fg` num inteiro?

```
if (connectionIsOpened)
    {
String s = "INSERT INTO jogador(nome) VALUES " + "('" + this.playerName + "'" + ")";
        connection.executeUpdate(s);

        String fg = "SELECT cod_jogador FROM jogador WHERE jogador.nome = " + "'" + this.playerName + "'"; //buscar cod_jogador onde nome_jogador = this.playerName
        connection.executeQuery(fg);
        int gh = Integer.parseInt(fg);
        String a ="INSERT INTO `jogos`( `cod_jogador`, `pontuacao`) VALUES " + "(" + gh + "," + this.points + ")"; //Inserir cod_jogador e pontuação onde nome_jogador = this.playernames
        connection.executeUpdate(a);
        connection.close();

    }
```

Comment: `fg` definitivamente não é inteira. Você não gostaria de resgatar o `ResultSet` retornado pela conexão ao executar `fg` e então `rs.getInt("cod_jogador")`?

Comment: Pelo codigo, voce nao precisa converter nada, apenas resgatar o valor de cod_jogador, ja que vai inserir em outra query. Apesar de achar que ai seria o caso de uma subquery ao inves de duas consultas.

Comment: Boa tarde Articuno, é mesmo isso que eu necessito. Como fazer?

Comment: seu c'odigo esta vulneravel para SQL Injection

Answer (score 1):

Se a coluna da sua tabela é do tipo `int`, você precisa pegar o valor do [`Resultset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), através do método [`getInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt-int-):

```
if (connectionIsOpened)
    {
        String s = "INSERT INTO jogador(nome) VALUES " + "('" + this.playerName + "'" + ")";
        connection.executeUpdate(s);

        String fg = "SELECT cod_jogador FROM jogador WHERE jogador.nome = " + "'" + this.playerName + "'"; //buscar cod_jogador onde nome_jogador = this.playerName
        ResultSet rs = connection.executeQuery(fg);

        if(rs.next()){
            int gh = rs.getInt(1);
            String a ="INSERT INTO `jogos`( `cod_jogador`, `pontuacao`) VALUES " + "(" + gh + "," + this.points + ")"; //Inserir cod_jogador e pontuação onde nome_jogador = this.playernames
            connection.executeUpdate(a);    
        }

        connection.close();

}
```

Só lembrando que você precisa adicionar o import: `import java.sql.ResultSet;`.

Obs.: vale ressaltar que, como foi alertado pelo [@ThiagoLoureiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274171/converter-string-em-int/274172#comment562488_274171) seu código pode estar vulnerável, caso estas variáveis que você está concatenando na query estejam vindo de entrada de usuário, como campos de texto. [Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275670/28595) tem uma exemplificação do uso de `PreparedStatement` e outros links úteis a respeito.

Comment: Creio que é proximo do que pretendo obter mas o que é o "ResultSet" mesmo?

Comment: @DiogoNeves é uma interface que se usa para recuperar dados advindos do banco de dados, pela classe Statemente ou PrepareStatement.

Comment: Sim sim, eu entendi mas no BlueJ, dá o seguinte erro "cannot find symbol - class ResultSet";

Comment: @DiogoNeves você importou a classe?